# I found inconsistency in Scala's underscore

Tags: scala, lambda, anonymous-function, scala-placeholder-syntax

This works: `(1 to 5).reduceLeft( _+_ )`

but this doesn't: `(x:Int,y:Int)=>_+_`

```
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
              (x:Int,y:Int)=>_+_
                             ^
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
              (x:Int,y:Int)=>_+_
                               ^
```

It is in way of inconsistent, since in the first case the anonymous function (`_+_`) compiled successfully, but failed for the second case.

Is there something I've missed or am mistaken about? Or is it just the syntax definition?

Comment: you probably meant something like: `val f: Function2[Int,Int,Int] = _ + _`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no inconsistency. In the first case you're creating anonymous function with two arguments which are then added, that is, something like this:

```
(1 to 5).reduceLeft((x, y) => x + y)
```

In the second case, however, you're creating anonymous function which *returns another anonymous function* with two arguments:

```
(x: Int, y: Int) => ((a, b) => a + b)
```

(It seems that you thought that `(x: Int, y: Int) => _+_` is the same as `(x: Int, y: Int) => x + y`, and this is not so.)

In the first case you used `_ + _` in a context where types of its arguments are known (as a parameter of `reduceLeft`). In the second case you seem to use it in a context where type of the parameters of the inner function cannot be deduced, and that's exactly what your error is about.

Comment: got it, I misuse the underscores. Thanks your very helpful answer.